# ASP.Net C# and Microsoft SQL Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

My project is in webform1 in asp.net  include a textbox and a save
 button, when user enters some country name in textbox it should then
 click save button the name should be get saved in database table named
 country.
     then in webform2 the saved countries should load in dropdownlist on page load, then there should be some textbox in which user will
 enter state for the selected country in dropdownlist , 
     and in last in webform3 countries load in dropdownlist when user select a country , it should load states for that country in another
 dropdownlist and when user select a state from second dropdownlist and
 enter a city for that state , it should get saved in database by
 clicking save button.
     i am having problem at when i run webform2 the countries get loaded in dropdown list1 but when i select a country it does not load
 the states for that country in dropdownlist2.
     any help?
     here's my code so far,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace assign1 {
    public partial class city: System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (IsPostBack == false) {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAFIZ_HARRON; Database = 7thSemester; Integrated Security = true");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT CName,CID FROM country", conn);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                ddlCountry.DataSource = dt;
                ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CName";
                ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CID";
                ddlCountry.DataBind();
            }


        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAFIZ_HARRON; Database = 7thSemester; Integrated Security = true");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO city(CIName,SID,CID) Values('" + txtCity.Text + "','" + ddlState.SelectedIndex + "','" + ddlCountry.SelectedIndex + "')", conn);




            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }

        protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            /* SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAFIZ_HARRON; Database = 7thSemester; Integrated Security = true");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT SName,SID FROM state", conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            ddlState.DataSource = dt;
            ddlState.DataTextField = "SName";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "SID";
            ddlState.DataBind(); */

        }

        protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAFIZ_HARRON; Database = 7thSemester; Integrated Security = true");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT SName,SID FROM state", conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            ddlState.DataSource = dt;
            ddlState.DataTextField = "SName";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "SID";
            ddlState.DataBind();
        }
    }
}


----------
```

Comment: Selecting states for a specific country requires that you set the condition Country=??? otherwise you load every state in your table. Is this that happens now ? And what is the structure of the table _state_ ?

Comment: table state i used stateid , stateName, and (countryid )from country table

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAFIZ_HARRON; Database = 7thSemester; Integrated Security = true");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT SName,SID FROM state WHERE CID=", conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
how can i set condition for country da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT SName,SID FROM state WHERE CID=???", conn); ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax update panel of ASP.NET
it would completely solve the problem
in triggers you can specify the selected index changed event

Answer (score 2):

When you receive the `ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged` you need to prepare a query that selects only the states that belong to the current country selected.

So your code should be

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(.....))
     using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
     {
        string cmdText = @"SELECT SName,SID FROM state WHERE CID=@country";
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlCountry.SelectedValue;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ddlState.DataSource = dt;
        ddlState.DataTextField = "SName";
        ddlState.DataValueField = "SID";
        ddlState.DataBind();
    }
 }
```

Here the query text isn't built concatenating strings but using a parameter placeholder *(WHERE CID=@country)* and then adding the parameter required with the exact datatype (I suppose an integer) to the Parameters collection of the SelectCommand.

A few words also about the using statement. This  is the preferred way to employ a disposable objects because the using block ensures that the object is disposed when exiting the block.

Finally, your connection string should be stored in the web.config file, otherwise, if you ever need to change any detail of this string, you are forced to search every place in your app where you have hard coded that string